# image pathway in joomla module

Tags: php, css, joomla

I am creating a module in joomla 2.5 at here in default.php file i am using this code for calling a image

```
       <img src="/home_interior/templates/business13/images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
```

the image is store in this location

```
       wamp\www\home_interior\templates\business13\images
```

but in front end image is not displaying,anyone help me.

Comment: The first slash before home_interior may be throwing it off if you are using a linux based system.  It's looking for "/home_interior" in your root directory.  remove that.  If that doesn't work, what happens when you use the full filename, for example "C:/home_interior/.../img1.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are creating a module it should be located at `joomla_root/modules/mod_yourname/`. If that is so, it seems strange to link to an image located in the template folder. The module should provide its own image, preferably located at `joomla_root/media/mod_yourname/images/`.

Now, to write that image element I recommend you to use [JHTML::image](http://docs.joomla.org/JHtml%3a%3aimage/11.1).

```php
public static function image (
    $file
    $alt
    $attribs=null
    $relative=false
    $path_only=false
)
```

Example:

```php
<?php
echo JHTML::image('templates/business13/images/img1.jpg', 'Alt text');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `JURI::root` like this to show your image in the front end.

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'templates/business13/images/img1.jpg';?>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JURI::root()` to define the root directory which will work for localhosts and online, like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root(). 'templates/business13/images/img1.jpg' ; ?>" alt="Image 1" />
```

Note: you should also add text in the `alt=""` as it is required in HTML standards.